# Finding Area Between Two Graphs

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I just finished the chapter in my textbook about finding the area trapped between two graphs. However, I have a few additional questions. To find the area, you usually find the definite integral of the upper graph minus the lower graph. However, how do you know which graph is above the other? Or does it not matter because area can't be negative, so even if you do mess up you can still neglect the negative sign?

Secondly, should you always first actually draw the two graphs before solving, because in some trickier problems you can't just apply the formula. For example: if we want to find the area between two graphs and the $X$-axis. I could really just use a couple pointers to solve such problems more efficiently. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to watch for the points where $f(x)=g(x)$ as well to ensure the areas aren't switching.

Comment: Do you usually graph the functions before reasoning?

Comment: If I'm looking at area specifically, then yes. The integral itself isn't an area but it can be interpreted that way if you're careful.

Comment: What do you mean by "area specifically"?

Comment: The integral doesn't always represent an area. It can mean a lot of things, especially in physics and other applications. Area is just an easy way to learn the concept but it's not what defines it.

Comment: Usually (talking in contest math pov) we never get to see equations which are easy to graph, that's where you can (usually) just subtract and neglect the negative, however it is not always difficult to trace the graph,  you can try intercepts (put x/y as 0) and you can always check if it is symmetrical about some point/line, whether the curve passes through (0,0). It would be nice to know which problem exactly motivated you to ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, how do you know which graph is above the other?

Ideally, you graph them, or prove algebraic inequalities about each function to show which is larger.

Note that some pairs $f,g$ of functions will not always have $f\ge g$ or $f \le g$ on every interval, so the first step would be to find all intersection points, i.e. all points where $f(x) = g(x)$, and consider the portions of the real line those intersections create, and whether $f \ge g$ or $f \le g$ on each subinterval.

> Or does it not matter because area can't be negative, so even if you do mess up you can still neglect the negative sign?

This depends on the phrasing and intention of the question.

If you're looking for signed area, you might end up with a negative answer.

If you just want the total area, then you are really just looking for the area between $|f|$ and $|g|$, and can then use the previous explanation.

> Secondly, should you always first actually draw the two graphs before solving, because in some trickier problems you can't just apply the formula.

Getting a visual idea as to what's going on is always a good idea, no matter how elementary the problem. I would recommend graphing it, just in case; you can then use it to compare against your answer, just to make sure things make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot!